# Magento 1.9.2.3 - TTFB slowness on some pages

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a quick question for you, maybe some of you will have some leads.

On the site of one of my customers I have problems related to the TTFB. I explain myself, on a major part of the pages we have TTFB of 387ms (homepage for example). On other pages this TTFB is at 9.7sec, no particular reason and we have no idea why this happens on these pages more than on others.

Without any apparent reason or explanation, if some people have tracks / ideas, I'm interested, thanks in advance to those who will bring me tracks of reflection or a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to profile your code.

Magento already has a built-in profiler but I believe you will get better results the project [Magento Profiler](https://github.com/ecoco/magento_profiler/releases).

If you want a more advanced solution you can try [Tideways](https://tideways.com/) or [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io/).

Any of these tools will help you pinpoint what is taking so long to load some of the pages.